# Set timeout on npm clickhouse query

Tags: javascript, npm, clickhouse

In the following code, how to set timeout to query execution?
I've tried this timeout property but it's not working.

```
const results = await clickhouse.query(query, {
  timeout: 50,
}).toPromise();
```

i've tried config timeout in this .query function.
in the connection configuration i've tried session_timeout in the config object and timeout in the reqParams object but my in the query i can't make configuration works.

i'm using this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clickhouse

Comment: 50 milliseconds is very short. Are you sure you use the timeout parameter as expected by the clickhouse

Comment: In the example, the 50ms are to intentionally fail and confirm the configuration works, later I will increase it to 1 second, I know that my query takes an average of 300ms but I can't configure the timeout so that it fails.

Comment: Please update your question with this information IN ENGLISH or ask the question at the pt.stackoverflow.com. Perhaps this is where you need to look: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#wait-for-async-insert-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```js
// timeouts in seconds
config: {
        send_timeout    : 10,
        receive_timeout : 1,
},
```

and
try to setup `max_execution_time` in query execution parameters (or on server side for profile of your user)

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity#max-execution-time